# YouTube Data API v3 Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

I am kind of new to writing code and using API's. I am not entirely sure why my program is not working the way I would like it to.

What I want this to do is provide the search results in the console before I can move onto what I would like it to do next; however, I don't think anything is being searched.

According to this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#http-request, the only required parameter is "part," so I *think* I did everything right? Probably not though, because from what I can tell, nothing is being searched when I try to search for a term.
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <form id="search-term">
            <p>Enter Name:<br/>
                <input id="query" type="text" name="Name"/><br/>
                <hr/>
                <input type="button" value="Enter here"/>
            </p>
            <div id="search-results">

            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $('#search-term').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchTerm = $('#query').val();
    getRequest(searchTerm);
  });


function getRequest(searchTerm){
  var params = {
    "q": "searchTerm",
    "part": 'snippet',
    "type": 'video',
    "key": 'I was advised to keep my key private, so I edited this part out'
  }
  url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';

  $.getJSON(url, params, function(data){
    showResults(data.items);
   })
}

function showResults(results){
  var html = "";

  $.each(results, function(index,value){
    html += '<p>' + value.snippet.thumbnails.high.url + '</p>' + '<p>' + 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + value.id.videoId + '</p>' + '<hr/>';
    console.log(value.snippet.thumbnails.high.url);
    console.log(value);
  })
  $('#search-results').html(html);
}
})
```

Comment: What's it outputting to your console?

Comment: It just says "undefined" for some reason. I'll type something into the input box aka the search box, and hit the "enter" key. The console just says "undefined."

Comment: Can you please add just ````console.log(data);```` right above that and see if we get anything? :)

Comment: It works! Thank you! Do you know why I got something from console.log(data) and not console.log(data.search)?  This might be a dumb question, but I'm still new with this stuff :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You probably want `data.items` instead of `data.search`

I don't see any mention of a 'search' parameter under the "Response" section listed in their documentation. See the response properties here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#response

Therefore, you can probably see some output if you `console.log(data);` instead of `data.search`

I recommend you check out [Google's Javascript API Client Library.](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) It might not be the best solution for you, but it's worth a try. [Download on GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client)

Example using `gapi.client.youtube.search.list:`

```
// After the API loads, call a function to enable the search box.
function handleAPILoaded() {
  $('#search-button').attr('disabled', false);
}

// Search for a specified string.
function search() {
  var q = $('#query').val();
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
    q: q,
    part: 'snippet'
  });

  request.execute(function(response) {
    var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
    $('#search-container').html('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');
  });
}
```

Comment: One last question. I edited my original post to reflect newest code. I was going to start a completely new question, but I figured I'd just keep it here so that I can keep everything "together." So I have everything working; however, no matter what I put in the input box, nothing changes. For example, if I search for apples or pizza, I get the exact same result back. I'm guessing it has to do with using "stringify." I think because we are sending information from a browser to a server. If this is correct, do you have any advise on how I should do this? I am not having any luck with this.

Comment: @LunchBox: ````"q": "searchTerm",```` change to ````"q": searchTerm,```` .. in order to use the variable it can't be in quotes :)

Comment: I thought when you used .getJSON, the keys had to be in double quotes? Should I remove the double quotes from everything in params? Or just q?

Comment: @LunchBox No everything else looks ok. Just so you understand the "key" of an array or object is its index. In this case the _key_ is ````"q"```` and the _value_ will be set to whatever the value of the ````searchTerm```` variable is (which is passed to the function) - So if your input box is filled with ````oranges```` it will ultimately end up equaling the same as ````"q": "oranges"```` Hopefully this makes sense :)

Comment: Yup, I misunderstood what you typed the first time haha, thanks, everything works great now!

Comment: No problem always happy to help, and others are happy to help as well, as long as you do a good job filling out your questions like you're already doing, feel free to ask for help any time. I like stackoverflow because instead of just being told to do something like on a tutorial, stackoverflow encourages explaining _why_ we do it that way, etc. I know it can be confusing at first, but stick with it, keep learning a little bit every day and soon you will be able to make anything!

Comment: One last question and then I'm officially done with this thread. The entire point of putting in things like "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/96k_8ywt22g/hqdefault.jpg" was my attempt to have a thumbnail on my page after you type in your search criteria. Do you know why it just shows the link and not the actual thumbnail? This is the last thing that I am trying to do for this. Edit: that "...jpg" part appears after searching for something, it's not there by default.

Comment: You're doing great with the javascript parts but you should make sure to learn the basics of html and css if you haven't already, as it will give you a lot more potential ways of doing things. ````html += '<p>' + value.snippet.thumbnails.high.url + '</p>' + '<p>' + 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + value.id.videoId + '</p>' + '<hr/>';```` What this appears to be doing is printing out a text link to the image and a text link to the video. I would do it like this: ````html += '<a href="https://youtu.be/'+value.id.videoId+'"><img src="'+value.snippet.thumbnails.high.url+'"></a><br/>';````

Comment: That fixed everything. I have learned so much from your help, thank you!